# How do I merge sets of EF entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, merge, entities

I would like to obtain records from two sources (i.e. 2 different connection strings) with identical model to storage mappings.

Something more-or-less like:

```
var db = new MyModel(connectionString1);
var set1 = db.Things;
db = new MyModel(connectionString2);
set1.Merge(db.Things);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that you want all of the 'Things' from both DBs in 1 list? If so, you can just use the `Union()` method I believe:

Change the last line to:

```
var allThings = set1.Union(db.Things);
```

Comment: that sounds easy i'll give it a shot